# Not Enough Water in Cities: Skylines

Tags: cities-skylines

I'm having trouble with water in my city.  I have four pumps and three treatment plants and it's more than enough to cover my population.  I have pipes covering the entire map and my water budget's maxed out.  Still, EVERYONE is abandoning due to 'Lack of Water.'  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are all the pumps connected to the pipes? Do you have electricity reaching the pumps?

Comment: Pretty positive.

Comment: Are your pipes properly connected everywhere and connected to the pumps? Maybe you accidentally have detached a pipe somewhere, creating a whole lot of pipes that aren't actually connected to the water pumps?

Comment: Are you facing electricity shortfall?Can you put up a screenshot with electricity & Water overlays?

Answer (score 15):

You need to have enough water being pumped, as well as sewage. Note the consumption is less than capacity in both water and sewage, seen here:

[image]

You also need to make sure your pipes are connected to the buildings, denoted by a darker blue coloring in the water view, seen here:

[image]

If either of these are not true, you will see the No Water notification pop up on a building.

Comment: Bad connection.  Got it taken care of.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

My answer to you is 11 months too late, but I hope this'll help others as well. My problem was that I had two different places for sewage and water pumping and I hadn't connected two of those places. That's why people in other island were complaining about not having enough water in their buildings.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference—
Another possible cause for buildings not getting water even when there is sufficient number of pumps and sewage and the pipes are all connected—- check your Budget. If your water budget is set too low that can cause insufficient water supply in spite of everything else being set up correctly.

[image: screenshot of Budget tab]